# Invalid aggregation order path

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

I am using ElasticSearch 7.6 with a `test` index that has the following mapping:

```
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "amount" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "group_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, i am using the following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "track_total_hits": false,
  "aggs": {
    "strategies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "group_id",
        "order": {
          "drawdown": "asc"
        },
        "size": 100,
        "include": {
          "partition": 1,
          "num_partitions": 100
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "drawdown": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "state.id = 0; state.cumsum = 0; state.max = 0; state.min = 0; state.diff = 0",
            "map_script": "state.cumsum += doc.amount.value; if (state.cumsum>state.max) {state.max=state.cumsum;state.id=doc.id.value} if (state.max - state.cumsum >= state.diff) {state.min=state.cumsum;state.diff=state.max - state.cumsum;}",
            "combine_script": "return state;",
            "reduce_script": "states.sort((x, y) -> x.id - y.id); int min = states[0].min; int max = states[0].max; for(int i = 1; i < states.length; i++) { int nextMin = states[i].min; int nextMax = states[i].max; if (max > nextMax && min > nextMin) { min = nextMin; } else if (max < nextMax && max-min < nextMax-nextMin) { max = nextMax; min = nextMin;} } return max-min;"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If i remove the order part the query works good, i am referring to the following piece:

```
"order": {"drawdown": "asc"}
```

How can i sort by the value returned by **drawdown** aggregation?

The error that i get is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
        "reason": "Invalid aggregation order path [drawdown]. Buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "test",
        "node": "jHJ3_eOLQ3iZZeHZPI_dFA",
        "reason": {
          "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
          "reason": "Invalid aggregation order path [drawdown]. Buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible -- related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622443/scripted-metric-aggregation-order) and tracked on [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486).

---

We *can* order terms aggs by [single or multi value metrics sub-aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order), i.e.:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "track_total_hits": false,
  "aggs": {
    "strategies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "group_id",
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "stats_agg.max": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "stats_agg": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

TBH I also cannot understand why a single-value scripted metric is not considered a valid aggregation sorter -.-

Comment: any workaround? can we not sort by an aggregator?? really?

Comment: We can but there are restrictions. Lemme update my answer.

Comment: Wait, you added .max ok, but can i do a similar thing with scripted_metric too ?

Comment: i do not know, maybe for example copying somehow the value of the drawdown agg. into annother and then sort it. Utopian?

Comment: No you can't. Go thru the github comments -- somewhere in there are reasons for that. Don't exactly remember what they are tho.

Comment: Bucket scripts (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) are worth trying here. Quite utopian though, as you said.

Comment: do you mean adding that bucket and then use the "sort" attribute inside terms aggr.?

Comment: no way... :( i need to analyze timeseries with such custom scripts, do you know another solution? maybe not elasticsearch.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Can you explain the bucketed drawdown?

Comment: Basically i need a max(running sum) - running sum to get the the highest / lowest point. But it is not a simple MAX(running sum of amount) - LOW(running sum of amount) the lowest point must be after the higher (it is a downtrend). Can i do that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "bucket sort"
like here
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8486#issuecomment-768323340